# Unable to connect related fields in Prisma

Tags: node.js, database, nestjs, prisma

**schema.prisma**

```
model Material {
  id           Int                  @id
  name         String?
  description  String
  version      Int?
  suppliers    SupplierOnMaterial[]
  materialData MaterialData[]
  createdAt    DateTime             @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime             @updatedAt
}

model Supplier {
  id                Int                  @id
  name              String
  name2             String?
  name3             String?
  street            String
  zip               Int
  city              String
  phone             String
  email             String
  emailToken        String?
  emailTokenExpires DateTime             @default(now())
  country           String
  activate          Boolean              @default(false)
  contact           Contact[]
  trust_level       Int                  @default(0)
  default_userlevel UserLevel            @default(USER)
  responsibleBuyer  String?
  registration_id   String
  sendInvitation    Boolean
  comments          String[]
  materials         SupplierOnMaterial[]
  createdAt         DateTime             @default(now())
  updatedAt         DateTime             @updatedAt
}

model SupplierOnMaterial {
  supplier   Supplier @relation(fields: [supplierId], references: [id])
  supplierId Int
  material   Material @relation(fields: [materialId], references: [id])
  materialId Int

  @@id([supplierId, materialId])
}
```

I have two tables that are related by n explicit many-to-many relationship.

When I try to create a new Material and then connect an existing Supplier; my code editor complains about a syntax error

**code.ts**
[image]

**terminal (error)**
[image]

Comment: Can you please share the query in a text format, it would make it much easier to replicate this locally.